# How do you get true .png alpha transparancy picture boxes in C#

Tags: c#, png, transparency, background-image

I have a background image. I want to overlay a picture box over the background image. This overlaying image is of a square with rounded corners.

the square is a .png file. When it shows on the form, it shows the square but with the same background as the form.

I understand when you set a background colour to Transparent it looks to the form background, but how do I get the picturebox to show the background image below?

The square also moves over the background image and it will need to keep the transparancy whilst it moves.

I know this is a very open question but would really help.

Thanks

Comment: The general idea was to make a user control and override the OnPaint method and use Graphics to draw only what's needed. Here's some project someone did just for that. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26878/Making-Transparent-Controls-with-C-and-NET-3-5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a sneaky suspicion that the desired result using a picturebox is impossible. As you are already aware the picturebox is not a "true" transparancy. it literally paints the color of the parent it resides in where there is transparency. For a true transparent look and feel of something moving across the page using GDI+ you will need to do custom painting with the OnPaint method as Yorye mentioned in his comment and draw the bitmap/image using the Graphics object of the form by using CreateGraphics() function.

Answer (score 0):

if you trying to ahieve a situation so that the form itself is transparent yet is presenting the background picture so the form looks as if it was the background picture you should simply use the TransparencyKey property.